# Adding text to existing txt file using repeated user input

Tags: python, loops, file, input, while-loop

I want to let the user add numbers to the already existing phone list. The program should stop asking for input when the user only answers with enter. Here is what i've got so far ( I don't know why it doen't work as intended):

```
nums = open('telephone.txt', 'a')
print('Add name and number, finish with <enter>.')

while True:
    new = input('Name and number: ')
    nums.write('\n' + new)
    if new == '':
        break
nums.close() 

nums = open('telephone.txt', 'r')
print(nums.read())
```

edits: made suggested changes wo result

Comment: What specific issue are you having which we can help with?

Comment: You use `new` for the file variable as well as for the user input variable. Use different names.

Comment: your indentation after the `while True` is incorrect. the line needs to be indented.

Comment: this will write an empty line in your file if you skip entering stuff - I suggest to reoder the check and the write operation and dedupe the duplicated name of your variables

Comment: Please don't edit your question like you did. It invalidates the given answers.

Comment: This is my first posting. I realize I shouldnt edit the question after receiving answers, sorry wont happen again.

Answer (score 0):

You have everything required, though redefining `new` within the `while` loop is causing the reference to the file to be overwritten.

```py
new = open('telephone.txt', 'a')

print('Add name and number, finish with <enter>.')
while True:
    userInput = input('Name and number: ')
    if userInput == '': break # If no input provided, stop listening for new numbers.
    
    new.write('\n' + userInput)

print(new.read())
new.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

python is making the variable new a file pointer on line one, and then making it a string on line 5, change the variable name of the user input

EX:

```
new = open('telephone.txt', 'a')
print('Add name and number, finish with <enter>.')

while True:
    usr_input = input('Name and number: ')
    new.write('\n' + usr_input)
    if usr_input == '':
        break
new.close()
```